# How do I setup a node_modules directory in a Heroku:Python application?

Tags: python, node.js, git, heroku

So my python web application needs to use a tool that is built on some node.js tools. Naturally I will place `node_modules` in my `.gitignore` and I intend on keeping it that way. Either way, I need to add another Heroku buildpack, easy.

```
=== staging-application Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/nodejs
2. heroku/python
```

I then do a `git push staging master` but Heroku responds with this

```
App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tgz
```

I've searched around for an answer regarding this but haven't gotten very far. Here are some files that may be of help in the investigation.

Here's my procfile

```
# Procfile
web: sh heroku.sh
```

Here's my heroku script

```
# heroku.sh
cd site

npm install postcss-cli
npm install autoprefixer

gunicorn run:app
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in "[Herokuにデプロイされない!](http://qiita.com/tatyamaguchi/items/5d2806d45bdab6744204)" (It is not deployed in Heroku!)

> rootディレクトリが違った (The root directory is wrong)

In that article, [Tatiana Yamaguchi](http://qiita.com/tatyamaguchi) mentions pushing the wrong folder as root directory, and said root folder shouls also include a `Gemfile`.

> I found that the root directory is one folder above and that pushed objects do not have a `Gemfile` in the root directory. So Heroku did not understand that what was pushed was Ruby.
>   So I reworked the local repository again and changed it so that the position where `Gemfile` is located becomes root.

That is: like "[Managing Gems with Bundler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler)", where it is recommended to:

> Create a file named Gemfile in the root of your app specifying what gems are required to run it.